# How to create two entities using springboot microservices

Tags: java, spring, jpa, microservices, feign

I'm using a microservices architecture, and I'm trying to create a userApplication entity which has all data necessary for a credential purpose only, that means basic info about my user, also i have another entity userData which have all the data for my current application, so i dont really sure how to match those two and also call userData service when i create a userApplication entity because each one has his own microservice

I tried to use Feign but I'm not sure how to do it.

//ApplicationUser

```js
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UUID")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "UUID", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false, columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)")
    private UUID id;

    @Column(unique = true, length = 20)
    private String username;
    private String normalizedUsername;

    @Column(length = 60)
    private String password;
    private Boolean enabled;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;

    @Column(unique = true, length = 100)
    private String email;
    private Boolean emailConfirmed;
    private String normalizedEmail;
    private String phonenumber;
    private Boolean phonenumberConfirmed;
    private Boolean twoFactorEnabled;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id")
    @Column(name = "user_datum", table = "user_data")
    private Collection<UserData> userDatum;
```

//UserData

```js
private String email;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private String address;
    private LocalDate birthday;
    private Double height;
    private Double weight;
    private String bloodType;
    private String city;
    private String country;

    @ManyToOne()
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "id")
    private ApplicationUser user;
```

//repository

```js
    @RepositoryRestResource(path = "users")
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<ApplicationUser, UUID> {

    public ApplicationUser findByUsername(String username);

    public  ApplicationUser CreateUserWithData ();
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand your plan. You have two entities that are connected to each other but want to manage them in separate microservices? That does not really make sense, I think, because then you spread one subject of your application over multiple microservices. Additionally, I don't know how JPA should be able to manage those entities. You would have to create classes for both entities in both microservices, which sounds bad as well. At the moment I think both parts should be in the same microservice. Do you have more information like an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience, you should import UserData class into userApplication. Then use feign to invoke userData service to get UserData datas. After doing it, you can use apache BeanUtils to copy UserData obj to ApplicationUser obj.